# mapView should throw "user prompt message". location couldn't befound

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app, after entering some parameters, it shows location in mapView. What I want is when a user enter some and that place can't  be located then it should throw a message that "could not find"....means "prompt message". How to do it ..any related answer will be appriciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a UIAlertView. There's a handy tutorial here: http://getsetgames.com/2009/12/02/iphonedev-advent-tip-2-how-to-show-an-alert-with-uialertview/

Comment: +1 for not just doing the work for the OP, but for showing a link to where they can find more information to help them

Comment: thank you prince..but i meant where to use in the code...any piece of code?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, you'll have to look at locationDidFail in this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html if you know how to use delegates it should be easy to implement but if you don't you might want to look here and see how CLLocationManagerDelegate is implemented: http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/